# When should I use a ellipsis in a Menu Item

Tags: user-interface, coding-style, popupmenu

When should I put ... at the end of a menu item?  I seem to remember reading some rules but can't for the life of me find them.

For context - I'm adding a properties option to a right click menu and am wondering if it is appropriate to add them.

Comment: Use the unicode ellipsis when possible.

Comment: Seems some one has already had a posting on this. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278655/when-should-i-use-a-ellipsis-in-a-menu-item

Comment: This is such a great question!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637683/when-to-use-ellipsis-after-menu-items

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One exception to the first two answers: if the whole **point** of the menu command is to open a window or dialog, then you don't need an ellipsis. For example, a "Get Info" or "Properties" command shouldn't have it, even though it's opening a window which lets you edit things.

It's only when the menu command's purpose is to do something else, but it needs a dialog or confirmation in order to do it.

Comment: Thankyou JW - that was the rule I was looking for.  I'd remembered reading before but couldn't recall it.

Comment: That's good to know. One thing, is that a Mac rule and is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Here's a link to the Mcintosh UI guidelines: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGText/chapter_14_section_3.html
They indicate the use of an ellipsis when the action needs a different window.  The doc spells it out well.

Comment: In that document, look for "is completed by the opening of a panel." That's what I'm referring to.

Comment: sblundy -- I think Windows and other GUIs have generally taken the same approach. It's not always obvious when to apply this guideline, though, so you'll see plenty of exceptions.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa974176.aspx says "Don't use an ellipsis whenever an action displays another window—only when additional information is required."

Answer (score 15):

As I understand it it indicates that the option will ask you something else before actually doing anything. The 3 dots are actually called an ellipsis, and if you check out the English use it kind of makes sense:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis

BTW I've noticed OpenOffice breaks this convention sometimes!

Comment: It's important to know the distinction between "... will ask you something else" and "open a dialog". As other answers point out, you only use the ellipsis when the action needs more information before continuing. If the actual action is to display a dialog (for example, "Help About"), no ellipsis should be used since no more information is needed to perform that action.

Comment: According to the GUI design guidelines (windows 95 edition!) that was at my last job the Ellipsis signifies that it will want more information from you.

Comment: To add some context to this, the ellipsis is supposed to reassure the user that an action isn't going to be completed after choosing the menu. This was especially important for destructive actions. Would you rather choose "Delete…" or "Delete" ?

Answer (score 14):

When the option will send the user to some sort of dialog where the user has to do something before a real change is made. Options without the ellipse take effect immediately.

For example, 'Save' doesn't have an ellipsis, while 'Save As...' does because the user has to input the new name/location of the file.

Answer (score 8):

It means that there will be another dialog box after you select that option, it won't actually 'do' anything.  There will be another prompt.

Comment: More correctly, I think, it means "more information is needed before this action will be performed". Typically that more information will come from a dialog box but I suppose one could come up with a UI that doesn't use dialog boxes in the traditional sense.

Answer (score 4):

To be exact, the rule is that if more information is required from the user to complete an action, then include an ellipsis. In the MS Vista User Experience Guidelines, getting a confirmation qualifies as "more information" (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511502.aspx). Commands to show Properties, About, Help, Options do not get ellipsis because no further information is needed to execute the command, which is "Show Properties" or "Show Documentation" or "Show Options." The File Open command gets an ellipsis because additional information is needed to open the file, namely the file name.

Answer (score 4):

If the menu is an action that the user will be doing, but the action won't be completed until we get more information from the user, you show an ellipsis, e.g.:

- Format Hard Drive… (we need to know which one, and the file system type)
- Save As… (we need to know what filename and type to save as)
- Print… (we need to know what printer and quality settings)
- Find… (we show a text box asking for the text to search for, and where)
- Rename… (rename to what)

As opposed to actions that will happen the moment you click the menu item, e.g.:

- Save
- Undo
- Redo
- Select All

Ellipses don't just indicate that a *dialog* will appear. i.e. if it's not an "*action*", then there's no ellipses, e.g.:

- About Gizmo
- Page Setup
- Print Preview
- Options
- File Properties

And asking the user if they want to do something does not count as "getting more information from the user", e.g.:

- Delete File
- Recycle File
- New Text Document

Answer (score 2):

Whenever selecting that item results in another dialog box appearing. For actions that happen immediately (think Save vs. Save As), no ellipsis.

Comment: Not just any dialog box, only dialog boxes where the user needs to enter more stuff before they can do what the menu actually said. Help->About will show a dialog, but it's not for the user to accomplish the task of 'seeing help'.

Answer (score 2):

*Originally*, it meant:

> An ellipsis (...) after a menu item means that after the item is chosen, the user will be asked for more information before the operation is carried out.  Usually, the user must fill in a dialog box and click and OK button or its equivalent.  Don't use the ellipsis when the dialog box that will appear is merely a confirmation or warning (for example, 'Save changes before quitting?').

(Apple Human Interface Guidelines, page 69)

Note that it did *not* mean "show a dialog box", even though that was often the consequence of this.  For example, on Mac OS (not X), the "Options" button in the Page Setup window had no ellipsis, even though it showed a modal dialog box.  No ellipsis is used because showing the options window *is* the operation.

(Tog on Interface, pages 46-47)

Of course, these days nobody cares about such things as human interface guidelines, not even Apple, so you can pretty much do what you want and still be more consistent than most any other application out there.

Comment: I think the "pretty much do what you want" recommendation is wrong. There are well established cross-platform conventions that should be followed, and the use of the ellipsis in menus falls squarely in that category.

Comment: Why "should" they be followed?  The most popular and the most usable programs in the world today don't follow anybody's HIGs.  By what metric is following them a good idea?

Comment: The words you (Alec) chooses mean different things to me. "HIGs" are guidelines specified by a vendor -- 'use _this_ for forward/back buttons, use _that_ for standard menus, use _other_ pixels for a border". I'm talking about conventions such as the use of an elipsis, the traditional menu structure of file/edit/view/help, that sort of thing. Sure, sometimes a program can break the mold and be highly usable (think: the ribbon in newish MS products) but by and large your average programmer should stick to standard conventions.

Comment: As for the why... pick up just about any research paper dealing with usability. I think it's an established fact that consistency (first with the system, second within an app) makes for easier to use programs because you leverage what the user has already learned. For every one "most popular and ... usable program" that defies convention, I can show you thousands that are not usable largely because they eschew convention.

Answer (score 1):

I've usually seen it in places where more input is required from the user before completing an operation. If your properties dialog is allowing the user to change properties, I would include the ellipses. If it's just displaying the information, don't include it.

Answer (score 1):

They usually signify that clicking on that entry will open a dialog window.

Comment: This IS a programming question, unless UI theory doesn't count as programming, in which case anything related to HTML/CSS/Design isn't relevant, as well as possibly windowing libraries.

Comment: There is more to it than that. See the comment I posted on Kyle Rozendo's answer.

Comment: This is too simplistic, there are cases when the button is only supposed to open a window to show information, those don't need ellipses. Its more accurate to say when you want to perform an action that requires additional input.

Answer (score 1):

It generally means that a `Dialog` will be shown when the item is clicked.

Comment: This is a common misconception because in the common cases such as File|Open, File|Print, File|Save a dialog is displayed but the actual definition in Microsoft's and others' UI guidelines is that the ellipsis indicates more information is needed before the action will be performed. To illustrate the distinction, it is generally incorrect to put an ellipsis on Help|About because displaying the About dialog is the objective of the command not an intermediate step prompting for more information before the actual command can be completed.

Answer (score -2):

You should add ellipses to the end of text only if you're truncating the text (this applies anywhere).  You should truncate the text if it's too long to reasonably fit where you're putting it.

Edit: interesting, I never noticed that **menus in Windows use the ellipses to indicate truncated text, but also use the ellipses on short text to indicate that more information will be collected before the action is taken**.  **This is inconsistent interface design**, but since menus are under the control of individual programmers it's unavoidable.

Comment: I think you're being down-voted because your answer is incorrect. You said you should use ellipses "only if you're truncating the text" and that's simply untrue. 

Ellipses have meant "more information is required" on menus on just about all platforms probably since menus were first invented.

Comment: I didn't say I didn't deserve any down-votes. :)  I totally misunderstood his question as being about when he should abbreviate his own menu items, which made the question seem totally stupid (when it was just me being stupid).

Comment: That being said, I have to admit that this is the first time I ever noticed that the ellipses in a menu always (or usually) indicate that more info will be collected before the action is taken. Go ahead and give me another downvote.

Answer (score -3):

It usually means it'll take your focus away from the current window. Like for example, notepad has a "Find..." which means you're going to focus on another window (ie dialog box) to enter something. But in firefox, it has just "Find" which then focuses on a text input on the same window.