# Should "options" button next to dropdown use "..." or ">>"?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I currently have a drop-down where a filter is selected to be applied to a table. We would like that filter to have a few options on how it should be applied, so we have created a button next to the dropdown.

The design looks like this:

```
------------------  -----------
| Filter       v |  | Options |
------------------  -----------
```

However, we are limited on space and don't want to put much text in the button. Thus, we are debating between two implementations.

```
------------------  ------
| Filter       v |  | >> |
------------------  ------

------------------  -------
| Filter       v |  | ... |
------------------  -------
```

I believe that using the ellipsis (`...`) has a precedent in applications, but cannot find an example.

Is there a standard which should be applied here?

Comment: If you do use an ellipsis, be sure to use an ellipsis (…) and not just three periods (...).

Comment: As Swing (as Java) is multi-platform this should be done according to UI guide lines (if any) of the target/running platform. If there are no guide lines it is a matter of taste, but be shure to use it uniformly.

Comment: Joshua Taylor, I am... I just didn't add it into SO.

Comment: This question should go to ux.stackexchange.com, it's about user interface design, not strictly technical.

Comment: @ammoQ Agreed. Why is there no suitable migration option available in the Closing -> Off-Topic -> Migration menu?

Comment: Didn't realize that was a site. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ellipsis generally means "I'm going to ask for more details", so file/open will have an ellipsis next to the command button to indicate that the app will pop up a dialog to ask which file you want opened.

This standard was set by Microsoft in their style guide, so its pretty much universal in Windows apps.

The >> tends to mean "and more options are available", so you have a button that you can click to expand the set of options to list less-used, or advanced choices.

The difference is that ... means "choose and I'll ask for more info", `>>` means "choose more".

Given your use-case I'd probably go with the `>>`.

Ah - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637683/when-to-use-ellipsis-after-menu-items) for some canonical documentation.

Comment: Do you have a link to that guide?