# Should I use buttons with ellipses in web design?

Tags: web, button, ellipsis

I know when and why ellipsis are used in menus and buttons for desktop applications (see [When to use ellipsis after menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637683/when-to-use-ellipsis-after-menu-items)). However, I am not sure if this also applies to websites.

Comment: Probably more appropriate for [ux.se]